# Why Dummit-Foote text often skipped non-emptyness?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I noted that the Dummit-Foote text often (not always though) skipped the condition of non-emptyness in defining certain terms e.g. in group the condition that the base set needs to be nonempty isn't taken into consideration and so for the set the $A$ on which a group act in course of defining group action. However in defining the set of all permutations on a set $\Omega,$ it's taken to be nonempty. Please help me to get why the authors follow such convention which goes against (I don't if it really is) the standard definitions of those terms.

Comment: The group axioms require the existence of an identity element, thus guaranteeing non-emptiness.

Comment: For the group itself, non-emptiness follows from the existence of a unit. Every group acts (albeit in a rather uninteresting way) on the empty set, so there's no need to require the set the group acts on to be non-empty.

Comment: @TonyK,@Daniel Fisher: Yep! That's also a little bit confusing. The axiom for the existence of identity says $\exists~e\in G~s.t.~ge=eg=g~\forall~g\in G.$ But if $G$ doesn't contain any element at all isn't the condition follow by default?

Comment: $\exists e$ means there really exists an $e$. And in the $\forall g$, the universe over which the universal quantification roams includes at least $e$.

Comment: Sounds like a cool book name: "Theory of empty groups".

Comment: @TonyK Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @rfauffar Sounds like a *short* book. Perhaps with no pages...

Answer (score 9):

The group axioms require the existence of an identity element, which guarantees non-emptiness.