# The Dummit-Foote text tell to show the action is faithful. But I can see it's not if $V=\{0\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

The Dummit-Foote text tell to show the action is faithful. But I can see it's not if $V=\{0\}.$

Am I wrong?

Comment: I think this is linked with this previous [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/480664/8581).

Comment: What is the problem statement?

Comment: Prove that in Example 2 in this section the action is faithful.

Comment: @SritiMallick: But you know that when is an action doing faithfully??

Comment: When the kernel of the action is identity.

Comment: I still can't find the context of this question. What is the title and edition of the book, and the page numbers of the example and the exercise?

Comment: @ChrisCulter: I found it. Page 43 in Examples.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the case $n=0$. However, it's reasonable to assume from the notation $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ that $n\geq 1$, so you can just prove it in that case.